# Azure Service Bus Trigger is not processing session based queue concurrently

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure Function that triggers on a Session Enabled Queue, defined like this

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("QueueName", Connection = "ServicebusConnectionString",
   IsSessionsEnabled = true)] string queueItem)
```

My issue is that the function is only processing messages one at a time. Because of this, it takes a lot longer to finish a session than necessary. How do I make the function process messages concurrently?

I am currently relying on default values for configuration of the trigger, I have nothing explicitly set in my host.json.

I am using the newest version of Azure Functions, with the Isolated Model: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My issue is that the function is only processing messages one at a time. Because of this, it takes a lot longer to finish a session than necessary. How do I make the function process messages concurrently?

That's by design. A Service Bus session can only be processed by a single consumer to ensure message ordering. If you need to process messages concurrently and OK with out-of-order processing, you could use non-session queues.

But if you're looking to speed up processing, then batching could help. The trigger will be given more than one message, rather than just a single message.

```
public static Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "subscription", IsBatched = true)] string[] messages,
    FunctionContext context)
{
   // your code
}
```

The Isolated Worker SDK [configuration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/455#issuecomment-845055452) shows how to configure the max.

I am not sure you can mix sessions and batches though.

Comment: Thank you for responding Sean! Our issue is that our clients can each start multiple large jobs that each consist of multiple "chunks" that need processing. Up until now we have been using a single queue for all chunks, but this is starting to seem like a bottleneck. Clients will start a job, but will have to wait for each previous job from other clients to complete processing before before we can get to them. I thought sessions would be a way to handle this, where we assign the job ID as a session ID to each chunk, thus being able to process many jobs in parallel.

Comment: That will work. Multiple sessions can be processed concurrently. It's within a given session only one function instance/thread can receive and process messages from that session. Which is expected band aligned with what you need.

Comment: That makes sense. I had just expected that the single function instance could fetch multiple message at once from the session and handle them concurrently, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding how session based queues should be used. It can take upwards of 1 minute to handle one message and a job can consist of thousands of messages. If we're only able to handle one message at a time per job, the processing time per job would be unacceptable for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other option might be using sessions + partitioned queues/topics together to speedup ordered processing

Useful docs:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmatDG4yEgI&ab_channel=CiaranO%27Donnell
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/partitioned-service-bus-queues-and-topics/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32025329)